# cursor not changing to pointer in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm sure this is very basic, but can anyone help me figure out why the cursor doesn't change to a pointer when it is moved over one of the buttons?

js/jquery 1.11

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // if cursor over button, toggle pointer
    if ($("grow").is(":mouseover") || $("done").is(":mouseover") || $("search").is(":mouseover") || $("learn").is(":mouseover"))){
    $('selector').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
}
}
```

html

```
<body>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="text" name="input" value=""><br>

<input  type="submit" value="grow">
<input type="submit" value="done">
<input type="submit" value="search">
<input type="submit" value="learn">
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Can't you just use the css `:hover``?

Comment: What's `$('selector')` supposed to select? Or any of your other selectors for that matter?

Comment: Also remember the function you pass to `$(document).ready()` will only be fired once on DOM load, not for any other event. See [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's for various reasons, but the only code you need is that:

```
input:hover {
     cursor:pointer;
}
```

That's pure CSS.

Your code is not good in the targets. That's no correct:

```
$("grow").is(":mouseover")
```

Because you are attempting to target a tag `<grow>` doesn't exists.You need this:

```
$("input[value=grow]").is(":mouseover")
```

Otherwise, you don't need a lot of javascript to make this. Just use the css above